# Common variable in abstract class

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have an abstarct class that is extended by 15 classes. All the 15 classes have common method code called exec(map: HashMap) : Unit. So I thought of implementing this code in the abstract class. This exec() code though has a side effect. It assigns a result variable to the output of exec(). (I cannot change the signature of exec because it is implemented from some external interface). The output is based on the map that was passed in by the implementing class.

So I'm confused, that if I implement the exec() in the abstract class, will the value of result vairable get corrupted?

```
abstract class AbstractMyClass extends externalIntefaceA{
  var result : DataFrame = _

  override def exec(map : HashMap): Unit{
  //some logic
  result = map.get(key1)
 }
  def eval

  def getResult : DataFrame = result
}
  
class A1 extends AbstractMyClass{
  override def eval(map : HashMap){
  map.add("key1","value1")
 }
}

class A2 extends AbstractMyClass{
  override def eval(map : HashMap){
  map.add("key1","value2")
}
}


class A3 extends AbstractMyClass{
  override def eval(map : HashMap){
  map.add("key1","value3")
 }
}
```

Okay not sure if I was able to explain it well, but would the result variable be corrupted by the different implementing classes? I would like the exec() method in the abstract class because the rest of the code in it is the same in all the 15 classes. So it doesn't make sense to override it in each of the 15 classes and have a local result variable for each class. Is there a best practice for this kind of thing?

Comment: What does `eval()` have to do with `exec()`?

Comment: eval()  is just  to show that it sets some value in map that is used in exec() to generate result. The external library calls exec() of each class automatically after eval()

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you are confusing classes and instances. `A1`, `A2` etc. are different classes that share some implementation from `AbstractMyClass`. But each time you create a new object of one of these classes, it includes a new object of type `AbstractMyClass`. Each object has a different `result` value, so calling methods on one object will not affect the value in another object.

However the overall design here is poor, and not functional. Using `var` is a bad sign, and making that `var` public makes it impossible to know who might have been modifying that value.

It would be better if `exec` returned the result rather than storing it, removing the need for a `var`. If the new value is required for subsequent calculations then that new value can be passed to those methods rather than being read from class state.

If it is really necessary to have mutable values, make sure they are `private` and provide methods to modify them. And avoid writing these values in the main processing code, to keep that part of the code functional. It easier to verify and test the processing code if it does not write any mutable values.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was, as mentioned I cannot change the return value of exec because it overrides another interface. So I understood that even if I declare & initialize var result in Abstract class and use it in the exec() of Abstract class, the class instances will still have their own result variable values after the exec method is called, correct? Would be open to hear any alternative design solution.

Comment: If I make result private in Abstract class, it says 'Abstract class cannot have private modifier.'  So I initialized result to _ and made it private. But I cannot reassign it to actual value in exec() method unless I keep it as var

Comment: Also if I keep result as private in AbstractClass, I get message class A1 must implement abstract result  or be declared abstract. var result is declared in externalIntefaceA. I can safely mark is a protected in AbstractClass without the compiler complaining. So my Abstract Class now has override protected var result : DataFrame = _

Comment: Okay, sorry making it as protected doesn't work at runtime. It says "overriding method result in trait externalInterfaceA of type => DataFrame;
 variable result has weaker access privileges; it should be public
  override protected var result : DataFrame = _"